# Create Laravel route to attach a Product model to Order model

Tags: php, laravel, url-routing

**Background Information**

I'm building an invoicing system...

I created:

- **Product** Model with a restful **ProductController**
- **Order** Model with a restful **OrderController**

Relationships:

- **Product** belongToMany **Order**
- **Order** belongToMany **Product**

---

**My Goal:**

From my orders/show.blade.php I want to be able to add more products to that specific order.

**What I've Tried:**

I created a form in the orders/show.blade.php view that hits this route below

```php
Route::patch('orders/{order:code}/products/add', 'OrderController@addProduct')->name('orders.products.add');
```

---

**My Problem / Doubts:**

Does this violate the Laravel Restful controller? Should I create another controller called OrderProductController? Is there a better way of accomplishing this?

Comment: you can do it by command line  :  php artisan make:model Customer -mcr

Comment: I would say you do not need a new Controller for this, it is valid to have it in the OrderController. Honestly you could instead have it in the ProductController since you are technically updating the Product. But I believe both are valid. I think the biggest thing is consistency. You will most likely run into similar cases with your app in the future so it will be important to keep the  code as uniform as possible. For you and for any future developers on it.